# Why does <input type="email"> mark valid email addresses as invalid?

Tags: html, email-validation, html-input

Per Wikipedia, these are valid email addresses.

```
" "@example.org
"john..doe"@example.org
"very.(),:;<>[]\".VERY.\"very@\\ \"very\".unusual"@strange.example.com
postmaster@[123.123.123.123]
postmaster@[IPv6:2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334]
```

`<input type="email">` rejects them as invalid.

Furthermore, per Wikipedia, this address is invalid.

```
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234+x@example.com
```

Yet `<input type="email">` accepts it as valid.

Why is the implementation of `<input type="email">` so imprecise?

I understand that the HTML standard specifies a particular validation regex that is consistent with this behaviour. But why is it formally incorrect?

Please note that I am not asking for a better regex than the default one or any other practical solution. I am asking for the reasoning behind the decision to let `<input type="email">` yield incorrect validation results in some cases.

Comment: Wikipedia is not a reliable source because allows multiple users to edit. Furthermore input tag it follows a regex you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email#validation).

Comment: I would assume that you have to ask this in the issue tracker of the browser you are using. I doubt there is a general answer for your question that matches the behaviour of all browsers

Comment: You can have a look here : https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#valid-e-mail-address for the spec of the email validation. Browser's implementation might differ though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation regex of the HTML specification is incorrect because the designers thought that a correct validation would be too impractical. To quote the reasoning from the [HTML specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#valid-e-mail-address):

> This requirement is a willful violation of RFC 5322, which defines a syntax for email addresses that is simultaneously too strict (before the "@" character), too vague (after the "@" character), and too lax (allowing comments, whitespace characters, and quoted strings in manners unfamiliar to most users) to be of practical use here.

Answer (score 0):

Email validation is done based on the default regex of the web browser.

Based on [docs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#valid-e-mail-address) default pattern is

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/
```

To overcome this inconsistency. Try setting your own regex using `pattern` field

```
<input pattern = "regular_exp">
```

##### Example

```
<input 
  type = 'email'
  pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$"
/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "that works"? The OP hasn't shared any regular expression

Comment: I wanted to direct the attention to the default regex and later setting own regex . I have made edit based on your comment to remove the phrase "that works"

Answer (score 0):

The email validation is supposed to be the following as defined by the [W3C HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/input.email.html)

> A single e-mail address.
>
> Value: Any string that matches the following [[ABNF]](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/references.html#refsABNF) production:
>
> ```
> 1*( atext / "." ) "@" ldh-str 1*( "." ldh-str )
> ```
>
> …where *atext* is as defined in [[RFC 5322]](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/references.html#refsRFC5322), and *ldh-str* is as defined in [[RFC 1034]](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/references.html#refsRFC1034).
>
> That is, any string which matches the following regular expression:
>
> ```
> /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/
> ```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email), it is checking to see if its properly formatted. It is not checking to see if it's valid.

If you want a larger set, then you can check it yourself in JavaScript or back at the server.

### EDIT

Since @TylerH mentioned it, and for completeness, here's the excerpt from [Whatwg Specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#valid-e-mail-address)

> A valid email address is a string that matches the email production of the following ABNF, the character set for which is Unicode. This ABNF implements the extensions described in RFC 1123. [ABNF] [RFC5322] [RFC1034] [RFC1123]
>
> email         = 1*( atext / "." ) "@" label *( "." label )
>
> label         = let-dig [ [ ldh-str ] let-dig ]  ; limited to a length of 63 characters by RFC 1034 section 3.5
>
> atext         = < as defined in RFC 5322 section 3.2.3 >
>
> let-dig       = < as defined in RFC 1034 section 3.5 >
>
> ldh-str       = < as defined in RFC 1034 section 3.5 >
>
> This requirement is a willful violation of RFC 5322, which defines a syntax for email addresses that is simultaneously too strict (before the "@" character), too vague (after the "@" character), and too lax (allowing comments, whitespace characters, and quoted strings in manners unfamiliar to most users) to be of practical use here.
>
> The following JavaScript- and Perl-compatible regular expression is an implementation of the above definition.
>
> `` /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/ ``

Comment: Small nitpick but it's actually the [WHATWG HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#email-state-(type=email)) that is followed, not the W3C one.